# Copy event does not fire on safari

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, events

I have component which has a `div` element inside:

```
<div class="content-wrapper" (copy)="onCopy($event)" #contentWrapper>
```

And there is a problem with `copy` event. It works fine for Chrome on PC and Chrome on mac but there is no event on Safari on mac.

I also tried to add a `EventListener` to this `div` element:

```
this.contentWrapper.nativeElement.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  console.log('copy event');
});
```

But this doesnt work at all browsers. How can I make a `copy` event to be fired on Safari browser?

Comment: as per mozilaa docs, Safari does support `copy` event : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: Safari on (Mac) desktop should support it. It's iOS Safari that does not.

Comment: @porgo the (copy)="onCopy($event)" code works on my Mac/Safari. What OS and Safari version do you have?

Comment: I checked `copy` event by creating an empty `div` and there `copy` event is working. I think that the problem is because my original `div` has multiple elements and others components inside. But it is still strange because only on safari this problem exists.